# Unknown operator | when using data visualization and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-operators, tikz-datavisualization

**Problem:**

I am trying to get the function `y = |x|` to work with data visualization library in TikZ but without success. It seems the issue is with the operator `|`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes,
                        visualize as smooth line,
                        y axis={label},
                        x axis={label}]

    data [format=function] {
          var x : interval [-5:5];
          func y = |x|;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Desired output:**

To get the function to work with the operator `|`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertical bars are just notation, i.e. a common way to typeset the absolute value. According to section **94.3 Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Functions** of the pgf manual (version 3.1.3) the function is `abs` (and you forgot a `\value`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes,
                        visualize as smooth line,
                        y axis={label},
                        x axis={label}]

    data [format=function] {
          var x : interval [-5:5];
          func y = abs(\value x);
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Can one declare new math operators? *Yes.* Can one define an operator `|`? *Yes.* Does it work as you want it and is it safe? *Maybe not.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\pgfmathdeclareoperator{|} {abs}   {1}{infix} {600}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes,
                        visualize as smooth line,
                        y axis={label},
                        x axis={label}]

    data [format=function] {
          var x : interval [-5:5];
          func y = | \value x ;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to get the operators to work with the datavisualization? If not, how do you find the name of the functions to use?

Comment: @kexxcream The functions are given in section **94.3 Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Functions** of pgfmanual v 3.1.3. I added this information to the asnwer. And yes, you *could* make the operator work but this will be quite a hack, and most likely fragile. One of the problems is that `|` is already used in `||` for `or`, which can be used in `ifthenelse`. I strongly advise not to hack this.

Comment: @kexxcream I added a way to declare a math operator. It is a compromise between very hacky and the precise syntax you wanted. In this version there is only one `|` in the beginning. Whether or not this breaks anything I do not know.